# SSMA for Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, clob

It would seem that SSMA for Oracle won't work with SQL Server Express Edition.  In hindsight I can see why (no working SQL Server Agent with Express Edition), though I am irritated that the official download from Microsoft says **it will** work with **ALL** SQL Server Editions:

> ***> SSMA for Oracle v6.0 is designed to support migration from Oracle
>   9.07.3 or later version to all edition of SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, and SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014 and
>   Azure SQL DB.***
>   ref: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43689

Is there a workaround for this, aside from the obvious which is to upgrade SQL Server?  Maybe someway to just install a working SQL Server Agent?  I am guessing not, so as an alternative, is there some other (free) way to migrate an oracle DB to SQL Server?

Ideally, I would like to be able to migrate the entire DB (just like w. SSMA), but would be happy with just being able to migrate individual tables that include CLOBs.  *Note: The Import/Export tool that comes with SQL Server doesn't support CLOB migration using standard OLEDB.*

Thank you!

Comment: You could temporarily spin up an Azure instance as the migration target, no?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the solution to my question [full article here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssma/2011/03/30/migrating-data-into-sql-server-using-ssma/).

**Summary:**

GOTO: **Tools (*menu*)>Project Settings (*submenu*)>General (*lower panel*)>Migration (*upper tree*)**

Under "Migration Engine" be sure to select "Client Side Data Migration Engine"  This may be selected by default.

[image]

The migration will take longer, because of an extra data hop through the client machine (**Oracle->Client Machine->SQLServer**), than with server side migration, but will still work.

I hope others will find this helpful.